# Transfer progress on Clash of Clans from iPad to iPad Mini Ai3

Tags: data-transfer

My son has Clash of Clans progress on an iPad1 with my Apple ID that we want to transfer to a iPad Mini 3 with a new Family Apple ID. Is this possible and if so how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

This question has been asked multiple times on the forum. Did you perform a good search?

The simplest way is to log into gamecenter using the old apple id used on the iPad. When downloaded CoC and after playing some missions ( 3 or 4 i think) there should be a pop up aski g if you want to import your current town.